# What is the proper way to save form data in Laravel (using an injected model)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection

I'm trying to setup a simple form to save, but want to be sure we are using best practices, like DI.

In the controller file, I have

```
public function store()
{
    //get form data
    $data = Input::all();

    $newclient = new Client($data);
    $newclient->save();
    return Redirect::route('clients.index');
}
```

But that really isn't dependency injection. (right?) I injected the model like this

```
public function __construct(\Client $clientmodel)
{
    $this->clientmodel=$clientmodel;
}
```

How would I save the form data on the store function properly, using dependency injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the `__constructor` in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` you can see it uses `fill()` to assign the passed in values.

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();
    $this->syncOriginal();
    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

So you can just use `fill()` to do the same after the class has been instantiated:

```
$this->clientmodel->fill($data)
$this->clientmodel->save();
```

Or if you want to just save it anyways, you can use `create()`:

```
$this->clientmodel->create($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are always creating a new object then you can use the Eloquent Model's `create` method like so:

```php
public function store()
{
    //get form data
    $data = Input::all();

    $this->clientmodel->create($data);

    return Redirect::route('clients.index');
}
```

If it's possible that sometimes this route will be handling updates of an existing `Client` record then you should take a look at the `firstOrCreate` and `firstOrNew` methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is just a good practice. That'd save you a lot of codes. However, there are more remainders.

1. Always iterate over each input to check which input is absent. Well, in your case, it's a simple form. But if it's an API, clients send various inputs and you need to know what to expect. Sometimes when an input is absent, it can cause serious problems like assigning the value of an undefined input to a model.
2. Always check whether an input is valid. Make sure every input is up to your standard. You can make various validations to make it happen.

Other than the above two points, you've walked pretty far on the right track.